# MySQL dynamic pivot table

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

Im trying to get a pivot table with dynamic columns to work. When user_id is a string, it works fine but if its an int, then it seems to fail

Here is what I have so far with the assistance of past questions:

```
CREATE TABLE measure2
    (`inspection_date` date, `user_id` int, `score` int, comment text)
;

INSERT INTO measure2
    (`inspection_date`, `user_id`, `score`, comment)
VALUES
    ('2012-10-16', 0, 0, null),
    ('2012-10-16', 1, 0, null),
    ('2012-10-16', 2, 0, null),
    ('2012-10-16', 3, 0, null),
    ('2012-10-17', 0, 1, null),
    ('2012-10-17', 1, 1, null),
    ('2012-10-17', 2, 1, null),
    ('2012-10-18', 3, 1, null)
;


SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when user_id = ''',
      user_id,
      ''' then score end) AS ',
      user_id
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  measure2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT inspection_date, ', @sql, '
                  FROM measure2
                  GROUP BY inspection_date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eab24/1

Im sure its something simple, but what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the values are in `int` you are are making them the column names, you have to wrap the values in a backtick

The sql will look like:

```
max(case when user_id = 1 then score end) as `1`
```

The full query will be:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when user_id = ''',
      user_id,
      ''' then score end) AS `',
      user_id, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  measure2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT inspection_date, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM measure2 
                  GROUP BY inspection_date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eab24/11)

Comment: hello sir, As I Am digging some dynamic pivot table, this caught my attention.. and I want to know How this query works in php or how I could do this query in php

Answer (score 1):

Simple indeed - numbers alone aren't valid column names in SQL, so you need to amend your code to enclose them in backticks:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when user_id = ',
      user_id,
      ' then score end) AS `',
      user_id,
      '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  measure2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT inspection_date, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM measure2 
                  GROUP BY inspection_date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I suggest retaining this change for string values as well, in case some of your string values match reserved words or include spaces.

(Also, `'` aren't required around numeric values, so I have removed them from the case clauses.)

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eab24/12).

Comment: Thanks as well! You and bluefeet must have posted at almost the exact same time!