# query for horizontal layout of mysql data

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a table (delvery_dates) with the following fields:

del_id, del_date, del_ProductID

My normal query produces

```
    2014-08-23 | 25
    2014-08-23 | 32
    2014-08-23 | 14
    2014-08-23 | 15
    2014-08-23 | 56
    2014-08-23 | 34
    2014-08-27 | 32
    2014-08-27 | 11
    2014-08-27 | 19
    2014-08-27 | 35
```

etc

I would like a query that outputs in the following format:

```
    del_date, del_ProductID-1, del_ProductID-2, del_ProductID-3, del_ProductID-4 .. up to 6
    2014-08-23    25                 32                14             15
    2014-08-27    32                 11                19             35
```

I've seen somewhere about pivot tables, but I don't understand!

Any help much appreciated

thanks
Chris

Comment: Please add the `del_ProductID` value to your example (I think that's the one missing)

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers related with pivot tables in MySQL. Simply check [the search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+dynamic+sql+pivot+table).

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL dynamic pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773045/mysql-dynamic-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Pivot query. Since MySQL does not have a statement for that, you'll need to write it "by hand" (more exactly, create a dynamic SQL expression):

So, it may be something like this:

```
-- First you need to build the column list.
-- The "CASE ... END" expression will filter the data for each column
-- I use "max()" as an example; use whatever aggregate function you need.
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when del_ProductID = ', del_productID, ' then del_id end) ',
      'as `del_productID-', del_productID, '` '
    )
  )
into @sql
from example;

-- Now build the full SELECT statement
set @sql = concat('SELECT del_date, ', @sql, ' from example group by del_date');


-- OPTIONAL: Check the SELECT statement you've just built
select @sql;

-- Prepare a statement using the SELECT statement built above
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;

-- When you are done, be sure to dealocate the prepared statement
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Please [see this example in SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9404a/1).

---

**The explanation**

You may say "dude, this looks quite complex!"... but it's not complex at all (it's just laborious). So, how does the above solution works?

The first step is to build the column list and an expression to fill it.
The `group_concat()` function will take row values (or expressions) and concatenate them, separating them by commas. You need an aggregate function to show the values in the result of the pivot table. I chose `max()`  as an example, but you can use `sum()`, `average()` or any other aggregate function.

As for the [`case ... end`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) piece inside the aggregate function, you need that each column of the pivot table matches the value of `del_productID`, so, for example, `case when del_ProductID = 1 then del_id end` will return the value of `del_id` only if `del_ProductID` is 1 (will return `null` in any other case, you can add `else 0` if you want to return zero, for example).

The [`select ... into`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html) will store the result of the expression into a variable called `@sql`.

After you've built the column list, you need to write the rest of the `select` statement... that's done with the `concat()` function.

As for the rest, it's pretty straight forward: `@sql` is a string, so if you want to execute it, you need to create a  prepared statement using its value (which is a `select` statement), and execute it.

Comment: Gulp! I don;t understarnd this at all; I've tried to transpose this as follows, but I get an error message on line 3

Comment: select 
    group_concat(distinct
        'max(case when del_ProductID = ', del_product_id ' then del_id end) ',
        ' as `del_product_id-', del_product_id, '`'
    )
into @sql
from delivery_dates;
set @sql = concat('select del_date, ' @sql, ' from delivery_dates group by del_date);
select @sql;
execute stmt;
dealocate stmt;

Comment: @ChrisS What error? Which line? Check that all the expressions are correct (I wrote this with care, but maybe I missed something). Be careful with spaces, quotes and back-ticks

Comment: I missed a quote at the `concat()` part... I've just corrected the post

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Barranka. I've added the quote, but still get Error 1064 near         'max(case when del_ProductID = ', del_product_id ' then del_id end) ',
on line 3

Comment: sorry, it's near ' then del_id end) ',
        ' as `del_product_id-', del_product_id, '`'

Comment: I missed a `concat()`  function in the `group_concat()` block... sorry... I've corrected everything and placed a working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9404a/1)

Comment: Brilliant! I am very grateful for your  willingness to share yourexpertise.

Comment: @ChrisS Happy to help. (By the way, if you found the answer useful, up-vote it and/or accept it ;) )