# Assistance with an SQL Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

So I've got a table that looks like this: (called PRIZE)

```
Event_id    Place   Money
101 1   120
101 2   60
101 3   30
102 1   10
102 2   5
102 3   2
103 1   100
103 2   60
103 3   40
401 1   1000
401 2   500
401 3   250
401 4   100
401 5   50
```

And I am trying to answer this question:
'For each event, list the prize money available for first, second and third place on one line. Group by event_id.

For eg. one row of results would appear:

```
Event_id   First   Second   Third
101         120      60      30
```

I've got this so far:

```
SELECT Event_id, Money AS 'First' 
FROM PRIZE 
WHERE Place = '1'
GROUP BY Event_id;
```

but am really having trouble adding in the SQL for the 'Second' and 'Third' parts of the question.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!!

Comment: What about place 4 and 5 for event 401?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than executing multiple selects with subqueries, why not execute just one select statement using multiple joins?

```
SELECT tb.event_id,
       tb1.money AS first,
       tb2.money AS second,
       tb3.money AS third
  FROM prize tb
       INNER JOIN prize tb1 ON tb1.event_id = tb.event_id AND tb1.place = 1
       INNER JOIN prize tb2 ON tb2.event_id = tb.event_id AND tb2.place = 2
       INNER JOIN prize tb3 ON tb3.event_id = tb.event_id AND tb3.place = 3
GROUP BY tb.event_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using conditional aggregation:

```
select event_id,
       sum(case when place = 1 then Money else 0 end) as place_1,
       sum(case when place = 2 then Money else 0 end) as place_2,
       sum(case when place = 3 then Money else 0 end) as place_3
from prize
where place in (1, 2, 3)
group by event_id;
```

Note:  if there are ties, then this adds all the money for the places.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.Event_ID, 
   (SELECT Money FROM PRIZE AS p1 WHERE Place = '1' AND p1.Event_ID = e.Event_ID) AS 'First',
   (SELECT Money FROM PRIZE AS p2 WHERE Place = '2' AND p2.Event_ID = e.Event_ID) AS 'Second',
   (SELECT Money FROM PRIZE AS p3 WHERE Place = '3' AND p3.Event_ID = e.Event_ID) AS 'Third'
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT Event_ID
   FROM PRIZE) AS E
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for that 'ccStars' - should this work using mySql? I've copied and pasted it in and mySQl isn't liking it..

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one price per place and per Event_id this query should be good for your purpose.

```
Select Event_id
,FIRST=Max(CASE WHEN Place=1 THEN Money END)
,SECOND=Max(CASE WHEN Place=2 THEN Money END)
,THIRD=Max(CASE WHEN Place=3 THEN Money END)
from PRIZE
Group by Event_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want three columns then using conditional aggregation is the easiest way to pivot the data:

```
select 
    event_id
    , max(case when place=1 then money end) as first
    , max(case when place=2 then money end) as second
    , max(case when place=3 then money end) as third
from 
    prize
group by 
    event_id;
```

If you want a dynamic solution that gives you a column per place then this query (which is adapted from [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773045/mysql-dynamic-pivot-table)) would do that:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN Place = ''',
      Place,
      ''' THEN Money END) AS `',
      Place, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  prize;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Event_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM prize 
                  GROUP BY Event_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This would have the numbers as column names though, if you want ordinals you could create a lookup table and join with that.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abe59/4) with both solutions.