# MySQL pivot from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot

I'm trying to build a pivot table from three tables. I've been reading for example [MySQL pivot with 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172226/mysql-pivot-with-3-tables) but seem to get nowhere. Or have I been wasting my time and should have built the output in the programming language from the results of three queries instead of doing it in a single SQL query?

My tables are:

Table 1:

```
id | code   | description etc.
1  | paraA1 | ...
2  | paraA2 | ...
3  | paraB1 | ...
4  | paraB2 | ...
5  | paraB3 | ...
      ....
n  | paraZn | ...
```

Table 2:

```
id   | tr | set | etc.
1234 | 11 | 86  | ...
1235 | 13 | 86  | ...
1236 | 14 | 86  | ...
1237 | 18 | 86  | ...
1238 | 11 | 87  | ...
1239 | 12 | 87  | ...
1240 | 13 | 87  | ...
```

Table 3:

```
id  | table1_id | table2_id | value
345 |   1       |   1234    | 20
346 |   3       |   1237    | 17
347 |   2       |   1235    | 42
348 |   5       |   1235    | 33
```

And the output table I want is built with these restrictions:

- table1.code as columns, more rows could be added in this table so it should be done dynamically
- table2.tr values as rows WHERE set = x (i.e. for one set at the time)
- table3.value values as cell contents
- also blank rows and columns are included (in this example row 14 and column paraB2)

So the output from the above tables for set 86 would be

```
id | paraA1 | paraA2 | paraB1 | paraB2 | paraB3 | ... paraZn | set
11 |   20   |        |        |        |        |            | 86
13 |        |   42   |        |        |   33   |            | 86
14 |        |        |        |        |        |            | 86
18 |        |        |  17    |        |        |            | 86
```

Database structure for source tables unfortunately cannot be modified.

Comment: Generally, issues of data display are best resolved in application level code.

Comment: check out this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)