# Complex SQL Query Entity Attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. And i need a result based on the tables:

```
Table A: Users

| USER_ID |    NAME| VALUE |
----------------------------
|  1      |     Dan|     P |


Table B: Attachments


| USER_ID |    ATTACHMENT_NAME|
-------------------------------
|  1      |     ATTACHMENT1   |
|  1      |     ATTACHMENT2   |
|  1      |     ATTACHMENT3   |
```

I need the result to be like this:

```
| USER_ID |    NAME     |  ATTACHMENT  |  ATTACHMENT | ATTACHMENT |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1      |     DAN     |  ATTACHMENT1 |  ATTACHMENT2| ATTACHMENT3|
```

The value of attachments is dynamic for every user. But, the number of attachments is always 3. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Does the number of Attachments change dynamically?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi  The number of attachments is always 3

Comment: That's not complex, this question gets asked almost every day. Use the search function next time.

Comment: @fancyPants I have tried to search but i can't find one where the value of attachments is dynamic

Comment: First, you say above it's always 3. Second, here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773045/mysql-dynamic-pivot-table It's not that hard to search...seriously