# SQL Merge two rows with same ID but different column values

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to merge different rows into one when they have the same id but different column values.

```
    (table1)

    id       colour

    1        red
    1        blue
    2        green
    2        red
```

I would like this to be combine so that the result is :

```
    id     colour1    colour2

    1      red        blue
    2      green      red
```

There is no limit for number of colors. It can range depending on the id.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is colour1 = red and colour2 = blue and not the other way around ?   SQL tables/resultsets are by ANSI SQL definition **orderless**

Comment: .. also with the current dataset it is also not possible you need to have `id   |colour|position` -> `1|red|1`, `1|blue|2` ....

Comment: My mistake. The order can be anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL dynamic pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773045/mysql-dynamic-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

This would work for your specific example

`select left(colours,locate(',',colours)-1) as colour1
, right(colours, length(colours)- locate(',',colours)) as colour2
from
    (select id, group_concat(colour) as colours
    from table1
    group by id) concatenation`

not very general or robust.

If the set of values (colours) were fixed, I'd prefer to pivot it like this:

`select id, sum(RED) as RED , sum(GREEN) as GREEN , sum(BLUE) as BLUE
from
    (select id
    ,  colour='red' as RED
    ,  colour='green' as GREEN
    , colour='blue' as BLUE
    from table1) coded
group by id;`

but that wasn't the output format you requested.